# How to create a column that keeps track of the number of times the value in another column has occurred until that row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For instance, suppose this is the dataframe I have:

```
row    object_id
1      1024
2      1024
3      1024
4      1032
5      1032
6      1048
...    ...
```

I want to create a column `occurence_num` as follows:

```
row    object_id     occurence_num
1      1024          1         # starts count
2      1024          2 
3      1024          3
4      1032          1         # restarts count since object_id has changed
5      1032          2 
6      1048          1         # restarts count since object_id has changed
...    ...           ...
```

A method of doing it in SQL would also be helpful, but I want to be able to do it using pandas.

NOTE: I've found a way to do it in excel [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3617-excel-increment-when-value-changes.html).

Comment: If `row` 7 is 1024, `occurrence_num` should be 1 or 4?

Comment: @Corralien for my application it should be 4, but a solution for the situation where it would be 1 would be interesting as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cum.count():

```
df['occurence_num']=df.groupby('object_id').cumcount()+1

>>>print(df)

   row  object_id  occurence_num
    1       1024              1
    2       1024              2
    3       1024              3
    4       1032              1
    5       1032              2
    6       1048              1
```

Answer (score 1):

Input data:

```
   row  object_id
0    1       1024
1    2       1024
2    3       1024
3    4       1032
4    5       1032
5    6       1048
6    7       1024  # Case 1 -> 4, Case 2 -> 1
```

Case 1: occurrence_id of row 7 is 4

```
>>> df.groupby('object_id').cumcount()+1
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    1
4    2
5    1
6    4
dtype: int64
```

Case 2: occurrence_id of row 7 is 1

```
>>> df.sub(df.shift()).ne(0).cumsum().groupby('object_id').cumcount() + 1
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    1
4    2
5    1
6    1
dtype: int64
```